# Exclude BuildConfig.class from Android library jar in Gradle

Tags: android, gradle

When building an Android Library Project with Gradle, what's the correct way to exclude BuildConfig.class from the resulting .jar?

Answer (score 1):

Solved with `android.packageBuildConfig = false` which is deprecated according to http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system

Comment: Where does this thing go?

Answer (score 1):

here is a way to exclude from AAR:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

afterEvaluate {
  generateReleaseBuildConfig.enabled = false
}
```

here is the source from [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/6ilx6h/tip_to_libraries_devs_exclude_buildconfig_from/)